# Swift/iOS8 Sequential HTTP requests

Tags: swift, alamofire

I wrote some code a while back that logs into a website with credentials entered by the user and then navigates to a certain page to parse the information there (using `NSURLConnectionDelegate`).

```
func startConnection() {
    var url = NSURL(string:"https://www.website.com/psp/ps/?cmd=login&languageCd=ENG")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let data = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request.HTTPBody = data

    request.setValue("\(data!.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    connection1 = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!

    connection1.start()
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {

    if (connection == connection1) {
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.nexturl.com")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        connection2 = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
        connection2.start()

    }

    if (connection == connection2) {

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.nexturl.com")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        connection3 = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
        connection3.start()
    }

    if (connection == connection3) {
        let strData: NSString = NSString(data: responseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        parse(strData)


    }

}
```

The general idea is fire off an initial request and then send off other requests from the delegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading`. Is there a cleaner/better way to do this kind of sequential calling?

Comment: Use a framework such as AFNetworking that separates HTTP request logic from application logic, giving you a simple block callback when the request finishes.  Then you can chain requests by issuing new requests in nested completion blocks.

Comment: Yes as @David said, the best way is to use a closure-based HTTP framework.
AS in swift, functions  are closure the chaining will be very clean.
Delegate are definitively not the solution in this case.
Why do you want sequential calling?
You need to reuse datas from first request for second?
If not you can just make parallels Requests?

Comment: well all i really need is to authenticate the login. i'm looking into alamofire, the new afnetworking. thanks for you responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did it using the Alamofire framework (new version of AFNetworking):

```
    var loginRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"login.com")!)
    loginRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    loginRequest.HTTPBody = ("timezoneOffset=-600&userid1=\(username)&userid=\(username.capitalizedString)&pwd=\(pass)&x=31&y=12" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance

    // Chain requests
    manager.request(loginRequest)
        .responseString{ (request, response, string, error) in
            if response!.statusCode == 500 {
                return Error.InternalServerError
            }
            else {

            manager.request(.GET, "www.redirect.com")
                .responseString { (request, response, string, error) in
                    println(string)
            }
        }
    }
```